# POST GetAll Method doesn't clear data from previous request

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, postman

Right now I'm doing a test API I'm using Postman extension to test the POST methods on google chrome.
I have a database in my local server, I'm using VS2010 with framework 4.0.

My API right now has method GetByID working perfectly.

They all clear the data before sending the new one at each request, but this doesn't happen when i make a POST request.

Everytime i make the request the previous result stays there ( and if i change the parameters of the request the number of results stay the same but the data changes).

```
private List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();

SqlConnection con;
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

public IEnumerable<Employee> Post(string param1, string param2)
{
    ds.Clear();
    con = new SqlConnection("Server=xxxx; Database=x; Trusted_Connection=True;");
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Employee", con);           
    da.Fill(ds);

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        Employees.Add(new Employee() { 
                          FirstName = dr[0].ToString(), 
                          LastName = dr[1].ToString(), 
                          Id = int.Parse(dr[2].ToString()), 
                          Designation = dr[3].ToString() 
                     });

    }

    return Employees.Where(e => e.FirstName == param1)
                    .Where(e => e.LastName == param2);
}
```

My employee controller

```
static readonly EmployeeDetails repository = new EmployeeDetails();

[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Employee> Search(string param1, string param2)
{
    //Employee search = repository.Post(param1, param2);
    IEnumerable<Employee> search = repository.Post(param1, param2);
    if (search == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    return search;
}
```

I've been playing with this for an entire day now and didn't find any solution to the problem.
Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using Web API or MVC?

Comment: created project using asp net mvc 4 web application, than chose web api

Comment: In that case you should be using the `System.Web.Http.HttpPost` attribute, not the MVC one.

Comment: One note irrelevant to your post. It would be better to write one where caluse instead of two: Where(e=>e.FirstName==param1 && e.LastName==param2).

Comment: Christos I tried that doesn't accept it I really need to add another .Where

Comment: Try creating everything on a *per request* basis, my feeling is *something* is being cached. Rule of thumb - get it working, optimize it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys this is the 2nd queston i post on stackoverflow and again the answer is pretty simple and really stupid.

The variable Employees was a global one, and i wasnt cleaning it i wa cleaning only the dataset everytime it was calling again employees.

i just needed to add Employees.Clear();

Sorry for the time wasted :p

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of Cache try to add this attribute over post method

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
```

Comment: Changed the mvc to http and added this, still keeps pilling up the result everytime POST method is requested :\

Its probably something with the dataset, but i can't find any way to clean it :\

Comment: Ok guys this is the 2nd queston i post on stackoverflow and again the answer is pretty simple and really stupid.

The variable Employees was a global one, and i wasnt cleaning it i wa cleaning only the dataset every time it was calling again employees.

i just needed to add Employees.Clear();

Sorry for the time wasted :p